# What is a good JavaScript library or jQuery plugin for touch gestures?

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, gestures

I don´t need a full fledged framework like Sencha or jQuery mobile, just the ability to detect gestures such as swype or pinch to optimize some parts of my site for touch devices.

I have never worked with touch events so I dont really know where to start. Is there a light framework or jQuery plugin for this?

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-plugin-for-touch-swiping-part-1-of-2/

Comment: For the sake of completeness: There is a new kid on the block: http://interactjs.io/

Answer (score 14):

You can check those out: [Hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/), which you can run standalone or as a jQuery plugin,
[QuoJS](http://quojs.tapquo.com/), which is a microlibrary  it should work fine alongside jQuery.
If you are planning to use jQuery UI then [touchpunch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) should do the job!

Comment: What about pep? http://goo.gl/Y69w9b

Comment: Hammer.js is rather buggy. I've seen it fail to work quite a few times (the latest one being, it wouldn't fire `swipeleft`, `swiperight` in latest Chrome of Android)

Comment: @briangonzalez "jquery.pep.js" doesn't seem at all related to swipe gestures? It's a "jQuery plugin which turns any DOM element into a draggable object"

Comment: If you're using jQuery, try **https://github.com/benmajor/jQuery-Touch-Events**

It's the best one I've seen so far, with great documentation.

Answer (score 5):

[TouchSwipe](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/index.html) should meet your needs :)

Comment: or http://swipejs.com/ if you just want a slider

Comment: TouchSwipe looks nice.  If only they offered more than just a demo.  You know; like, how/where to download it.

Comment: Darrell Brogdon ? the whole thing is available on github - https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin

Comment: They need to link to that on their site then.

Comment: The link is in the top right corner: "Fork me on GitHub". But that's interesting, it indeed means that another mention should probably be added in the center part of the page ; you can propose it, page is also on github: https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin/blob/gh-pages/index.html :)

Comment: Odd.  One of my Chrome extensions may be hiding the "Fork me on GitHub" banner.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've tagged it jquery, I'll recommend [jQTouch](http://jqtouch.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I've written a jQuery Plugin: [TouchIt](http://danielglyde.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/touchit-jquery-plugin-for-touch-events.html) it converts touch events to mouse events.  The blog post includes a link to GitHub.