# Javascript event fired on long press/tap on tablets

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design, dom-events

I am developing a website using RWD principles and it is supposed to self adjust and work in both desktop and in tablets, and eventually in Mobiles as well.

I know in Android development we can catch a long tap event and do some actions.

But my question is that, is it possible to do it in HTML/HTML5 and Javascript?

Basically looking for a predefined event which gets fired on long press on html elements.

I have gone through [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625210/long-press-in-javascript) and understood all the alternatives suggested. Looking if anything new has been introduced in HTML5.

Comment: If this was possible, wouldn't you be largely overriding OS/Application specific context presses? That is to say, like overriding CTRL+C on Windows?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801058/what-is-a-good-javascript-library-or-jquery-plugin-for-touch-gestures

Answer (score -1):

Might check out [pointer.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pointer.js?utm_source=html5weekly) from Mozilla.  Apparently somewhat standardizes the touch/ mouse events into a single event type.  Probably better than using timeouts, I'd imagine.