# Need a zoom in/out , pan expressions

Tags: image, image-processing, video-processing, graphics2d, imagefilter

I was looking for expressions for zoom in/out , pan.

Basically the use case is this: Consider a rectangle of 1280x720 and I need to zoom in it
to 640x480. The zoom time is configurable, consider x seconds. The output of the expression should be all the intermediate rectangles (format = x,y,w,h) till 640x480 @ 30 fps. which means if the zoom time is 5 seconds, then I should get 150 output rectangles well spaced and smooth. (@30 fps, total rectangles = 30 x 5).

Further which, I'll crop them & then rescale them all to a constant resolution and finally feed to the encoder.

The same requirement goes to zoom out & pan-scan.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a mobile development platform (xcode, android SDK) then gestures are built in functions of the OS and are configurable through drag and drop.

If you're on a web development platform I recommend jquery plugins such as hammer.js or touchpunch.  You can find links to them on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801058/what-is-a-good-javascript-library-or-jquery-plugin-for-touch-gestures) question.

If you give more information on your platform i'd be happy to give you more specific examples!

Comment: Thanks Eric, I am on plain server linux. The goal is not to display any UI. The goal is to process an input image and get multiple cropped images (basically an image sequence for an operation like zoom, etc) and then encode them into a video. Here's an example video, that i want my output to look like  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ehl3xYIBP5U

Comment: Ah I understand what you're after.  What language are you working with to build your program?